# Customize the context ribbon of Outlook 2013 inline response

Tags: outlook-addin

I have created a custom Add-In for 2007/2010 and 2013. 
The addin - custom control appears well and neatly each time a new window is opened up / popuped. We can see the ribbon in the "Message Tab".

[image]

However if we try to an in-line or in response in 2013. The ribbon doesnt appear in the ribbon.

[image]

The development is all done using the VSTO code.
(Am not looking for any 3rd party tool)
I cannot switch over to XML based control at this stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the *TabComposeTools* idMso value for the tabSet attribute and the *TabMessage* value for the IdMso property of the tab attribute. For example, you can use the following markup:

```
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <contextualTabs>
        <tabSet idMso="TabComposeTools">
            <tab idMso="TabMessage">

            // your controls go there

            </tab>
        </tabSet>
    </contextualTabs>
</ribbon>
```

The Ribbon designer doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

This is great and works for me.

```
<contextualTabs>
  <tabSet idMso="TabComposeTools">
    <tab idMso="TabMessage">
      <group id="TabMessageGroup" label="Group Name">
        <button id="MessageButton" onAction="msgButton_Click" size="large" getImage="Favicon_GetImage" getLabel="GetRibbonLabel" />
      </group>
    </tab>
  </tabSet>
</contextualTabs>
```

Joe